# How can I avoid a sequence of inputs followed in the angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, submit

I'm learning angular, and I came across this problem. How can I prevent the user from flooding the program by entering the form several times in a row .. for example using this javascript:

```
javascript:for(var i=0;i<9999999;i++){ document.getElementByTagName("button")[0].click();
```

That's my angular code:
Component:

```
export class InsertTODO implements OnInit {
constructor(private angularFire: AngularFireDatabase) { }
ngOnInit() {
}
form_submit(f: NgForm) {
this.angularFire.list('todos').push(
  {
    name: f.controls.name.value
  }).then((t: any) => console.log('recorded data ' + t.key),
   (e: any) => console.log(e.message));
  f.controls.name.setValue('');
}
```

View:

```
<h1> WorkZone TODO </h1>
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="form_submit(f)">
  <input type="text" ngModel name="name" placeholder="TODO">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Insert</button>
  <button type="reset">Clear</button>
</form>
```

this is online on workzone.tk
deployed on firebase hosting

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Implement CAPTCHA, it will help

Comment: It really is a good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy to stop multiple post, by any mean if you restrict in your application (client side), still someone can use some automated tool to make multiple duplicate request to your website. For example if you use `fiddler`, you can play the same request any number of times. Even this is possible using developer tool where you can replay any request.

This can’t be handled at client side. You need to handle in server side only.

Following are the few of the approaches which you can try.

1. Implement `CAPTCHA/re-CAPTCHA` in your application. This is very easy
   to integrate and you will find lot of plugins in `Angular` to use.
2. You can also think of IP based restriction, if from a specific IP,
   you are getting multiple request, you can block it for some time.
3. You can always check at server side/db side if same record already
   exists, if yes then reject the request.